# woocommerce Calculate the difference between the amount in cart and our free shipping amount

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i want to calculate the difference between the amount in cart and our free shipping amount.

Example: You need to buy for 100$ more to achieve free shipping.

have this piece of code. which works perfectly inside codepen, and JSfiddle.. But when implementing the code inside wordpress, it returns a NaN? What am i doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<button id="knap">klik her</button>

<div id="cartPopupWrap">
  <div class="elementor-menu-cart__subtotal">
  <p id="pris" class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">1,500.20</p>
  </div>
  <p id="fragtPrisIalt"></p>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('knap').onclick = function(){beregnFriFragt()};

function beregnFriFragt() {
  setTimeout( function () {
    var kurvIalt = document.querySelector('#cartPopupWrap .elementor-menu-cart__subtotal .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').innerHTML.split(",").join("");
    var fragtPrisIaltTekstholder = document.getElementById('fragtPrisIalt');

    var fragtPrisIalt = "5800" - kurvIalt;

    fragtPrisIaltTekstholder.innerHTML = "Du mangler kun " + fragtPrisIalt + " for at få fri fragt!";
    },1000)
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your label is "Free Shipping", this will show "Free Shipping" when cart subtotal is greater than 100.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < 100 ) {
        foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
            if ( $rates[$key]->label === 'Free Shipping' ) {
                unset($rates[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

You can get more example here: [WooCommerce shipping fee that changes when condition is met](https://reigelgallarde.me/programming/woocommerce-shipping-fee-changes-condition-met/)